# static variable construction in C++

Tags: c++

How do compilers know how to correctly handle this code?

```
struct Foo
{
    int bar;

    Foo()
    {
        bar = 3;
    }

    Foo& operator=(const Foo& other)
    {
        bar = other.bar;
        return *this;
    }

    int SetBar(int newBar)
    {
        return bar = newBar;
    }
};

static Foo baz;
static Foo someOtherBaz = baz;
static int placeholder = baz.SetBar(4);
```

What would the final value of `someOtherBaz.bar` be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value of `someOtherBaz.bar` would be 3.

Static objects within a translation unit are constructed in the order they appear within the TU (note, there is no defined order of static object in different translation units).

1. First, `baz` will be constructed with the default constructor.  This will set `baz.bar` to 3.
2. Next `someOtherBaz` will be constructed via the copy constructor.  Since no copy constructor was defined, a default copy constructor will be used which will just copy each field.  So `someOtherBaz.bar` will be given the value of 3.
3. Finally, to construct `placeholder`, `baz.SetBar` will be called which will also change the value of `baz` (but not `someOtherBaz` since they are independent objects; while you created `someOtherBaz` based on the value of `baz`, they are different objects so can change independently).

So, at the end, you'll have:

```
 baz.bar: 4
 someOtherBaz.bar: 3
 placeholder: 4
```

Comment: @Samuel: I've a doubt. After the construction of `someOtherBaz`, using the compiler-provided copy constructor, will the assignment operator function be called for `static Foo someOtherBaz = baz;`? Else what's the meaning of the assignment here?

Comment: @legends2k - for single argument constructors, `TYPE t = arg` is the same as `TYPE t(arg)`.

Comment: @legend22K - there is no assignment in the code - the use of the = symbol is not an assignment, it is a copy constructor invocation.

Comment: @Neil: Oh thanks, makes it clear! If it invokes the copy constructor and not the assignment operation, in case if it's a no argument constructor, what if there's only one constructor which takes say two arguments. Did Samuel mean single argument constructors or no argument constructors?

Comment: @legends2K No matter what, T t = ... will NEVER use the assignment operator. It is an initialisation, not an assignment.

Comment: What if all the variables were in separate translation units, referring to each other via externs?

Comment: I guess that'll lead to a "static initialization fiasco" (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.13); perhaps Neil or Samuel can enlighten us here.

Comment: @wowus - there is no defined order between initialization of global objects in different translation units.  So if you had `extern Foo f1; Foo f2 = f1;` you may initialize f2 from the raw uninitialized memory of f1.